# more object types or more complicated objects best practice

Tags: java, android, object

For a bigger project, I want to keep track of some sensor values like speed, height and so on. They shall be stored, used and manipulated at different positions.

I decided to make an abstract class `ValueContainer` which every value type like `Speed` will extend. It will have the value and the timestamp for it. But in my statistics (and on other places) I want to have min and max values as well as averages for every type.

Now the question: do I create an object like:

```
Speed extends ValueContainer{
    long timestamp;
    Double value;
    EnumType type; // contains either avg, min, max or cur
    int elementCounter; // for avg calculation

    ValueContainer(Double value, EnumType type){
        this.....
    }

    void addValue(Double value){
        switch (type){
            case ....
        }
    }
}
```

or do I make objects that only contain what they need

```
CurrentSpeed extends ValueContainer{
    long timestamp;
    Double value;

    ValueContainer(Double value){
        this.....
    }

    void setValue(Double value){

    }
```

and

```
AvgSpeed extends ValueContainer{
    Double value;
    int elementCounter; // for avg calculation

    ValueContainer(Double value){
        this.....
    }

    void addValue(Double value){
        ....
    }
}
```

I am having a lot more object types there, but with less overhead and less confusion on what they do? At the moment it is just 3 types but going to be between 15 and 40 I guess. I already have an enum type and every class defines herself with it so I can pass on `ValueContainer` as an abstract to minimize the amount of methods on the interfaces `showSomething(ValueContainer a){ switch (a.getValueType){ .... }}`

Comment: I would also like to know it.  I don't know why some people downvotes this questions.

Comment: Is there a reason not to just use a `Map<String, Double>` and collate by key?

Comment: I would just use a `Collection` (e.g. `ArrayList<Speed>`) to store all the values of sensor's read, then implement `min()`, `max()`, `average()` as static method of the class. And SO is not really a good place to ask this kind of question (best practice) as it invites opinion-based answer.

Comment: the problem is that I do not know the amount of values I will have cause some statistics will be hold for an unknown timeperiod which could lead to a huge amount of values. these I cannot store in an ArrayList without huge costs therefore the avg with a counter. also, why would I want to keep all the values if I need 4 (current, min, max, avg)? seems a little useless to me? Sure it might be a matter of opinion but imo this it is with alot of programming questions. and the map idea: I want to assign every incoming value a timestamp, but do not need that with average values for example.

Comment: no other answers?
and to chryllis: I do not only have Double Values, this and the fact that I don't always wanna pass on the timestamp are reasons for the objects.